# Ubuntu 13.10 only for 9 months?

Tags: 13.10

Wont i be able to use my ubuntu 13.10 after 9 months??
Because it is mentioned that it will be supported only for 9 months.
It is the only version that worked correctly in my HP Probbok 4445s.

Answer (score 1):

You will be able to use ubuntu, but you won't get any security update anymore.

You will have the option to upgrade to ubuntu 14.04 LTS when it's out or go back to ubuntu 12.04 wich still has 3 more years of support.

Comment: Thanks a lot.

If i update to 14.04 LTS, will the softwares remain or should i install them again??

Comment: On a regular system upgrade software is maintained, if you are planning to reinstall it will not. In both cases you should always have backups if the files are important to you.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 13.10 is not a log term support (LTS) release. This does not mean you will be unable to use it when support expires, it does mean that there will be no official updates courtesy of Canonical.

14.04 LTS will be released in April 2014, and as such your hardware will likely continue to be as (if not more) compatible should you choose to upgrade.